# want to filter out following mysql resultset further

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, resultset

I am getting record as follows :
provider_id location_id | service_id

21 | 42 | 387

32 | 42 | 387

23 | 42 | 397

45 | 42 | 397

25 | 42 | 700

25 | 53 | 397

27 | 53 | 700

I want to filter out this further as follows. I made query for service_id 387,397 and 700 and getting record as per that.

But I want for each location all three service_ids 387, 397 and 700 has to be there. Now I am getting locations with 1 or 2 service_ids. I want to filter out these records. So that I will get all locations which support all three services for which search has made.

Also record has multiple provider working on (same or different) location for services.

Answer (score 1):

The following query does what I think you want:

```
select location, count(distinct serviceid) as numserviceids
from t
where serviceid in (387, 397, 700)
having count(distinct serviceid) = 3
```

It selects the service ids you are looking for.  It then groups them by location, counting the number of service ids at each location, and returning only the ones that have all three.

Comment: this will fetch records which has 3 occurrences or records for each services. but don't want that.

Comment: This filters locations that have three distinct service ids, and you are looking for locations that have all three.  This is how I understood your original question.  Do you understand the difference between COUNT() and COUNT(DISTINCT )?